# How do I assign a class to a jquery button var

Tags: jquery, css, class, button

Hello I have jquery that looks like this:

```
var autoStart = true;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.royalSlider').each(function() {

      var autoStart = true;
      var slider = $(this);
      var button = $('<button>pause</button>').insertAfter(slider).click(function() {

        if(autoStart) {
            $(this).html('play');
        } else {
            $(this).html('pause');
        }
        autoStart = !autoStart;

        slider.royalSlider('toggleAutoPlay');
      });

    });
```

I would like to assign some css to the button in this code, how do I assign a class to this button?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#1** The easiest way would be to just include `class='class-name'` in your definition of the button.

**#2** Second easiest way would be to add `id='button-name'` to the definition, then do:

```
$("#button-name").addClass("class-name")
```

... after the button is inserted into the DOM.

**#3** Third / hardest way would be not to add a `class` or `id`, and to work from the contents. You'd do:

```
$("button:contains('pause')").addClass("class-name");
```

---

**#1** is definitely the fastest also. No extra processing at all! Just do this:

```
var button = $('<button class="class-name">pause</button>') ...
```

---

To optimize even further, do this:

```
function toggleAutostart( autoStart ) {
  if ( autoStart == undefined ) autoStart = true;

  if(autoStart) {
        $(this).html('play');
  } else {
        $(this).html('pause');
  }
  autoStart = !autoStart;

  slider.royalSlider('toggleAutoPlay');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.royalSlider').each(function() {
        $('<button class="class-name">pause</button>')
            .insertAfter( $(this) )
            .click( toggleAutostart );
    );
});
```

Comment: Lots of options, thanks. Where exactly would I put the class definition? Do I do it within the code where it's first introduced (var button = $...) or do I do it in the next line somehow referencing the button?

Comment: Updated my answer for you!

Comment: Glad to help! I think that'll be the fastest way for you.

Comment: Updated my answer one more time for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass('classname');
```

Probably you want to check existence first... 
look at the reference: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

Create the element [**the jQuery way**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#example-1-1)

```
var btn = $('<button />' , {
      text    : 'pause',
      'class' : 'myClass',
      click   : handleClick
}).insertAfter(slider);

function handleClick() {
    $(this).html(autoStart ? 'play' : 'pause');
    autoStart = !autoStart;
    slider.royalSlider('toggleAutoPlay');
}
```